# how to instantiate set of map in java correctly?

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I want to have a `Set < Map <Character, Integer> >` instance. However I can't instantiate it with `new HashSet < HashMap<Character, Integer> >`.

I have to either change it to

```
Set<HashMap<Character, Integer>> v = new HashSet<HashMap<Character, Integer>>();
```

or

```
Set<Map<Character, Integer>> v = new HashSet<Map<Character, Integer>>();   // I prefer this one
```

Could anyone tell me why Java can't convert `HashSet<HashMap<Character, Integer>>` to `Set<Map<Character, Integer>>`?

Comment: The answers below are correct, but it's not really relevant in your situation - why should you want to put the actual implementation class of `Map` that you want to use in the generics signature? Since Java 7 it's possible to write your assignment in a shorter way that also sidesteps this issue: `Set<Map<Character, Integer>> v = new HashSet<>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simpler to show you an equivalent situation - let's use `Object` and `String` in the place of `Map<Character, Integer>` and `HashMap<Character, Integer>`.

Suppose we *could* write `Set<Object> set = new HashSet<String>();`. Then this code would have to be valid:

```
HashSet<String> strings = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<Object> objects = strings;
objects.add(new Object()); // Not a string!

String firstString = strings.iterator().next(); // Bang!
```

Do you see what's going wrong here? A set of strings isn't a set of objects, because you can add *any* object to a set of objects, whereas a set of strings can *only* contain strings.

Once you've got your head round that, port it back to your more complex situation: a `Set<HashMap<Character, Integer>>` can only contain `HashMap<Character, Integer>` elements... whereas with a `Set<Map<Character, Integer>>` you could add *any* kind of `Map<Character, Integer>`. So they're not compatible.

Answer (score 3):

Generics are not covariant.

Lets use standard example. You have classes

```
class Fruit{}
class Apple extends Fruit{}
class Bababa extends Fruit{}
```

If you create set for Fruits

```
Set<Fruit> myFruits
```

you should pass it instance of `Set<Fruit>`, not `Set<Apple>` or `Set<Banana>`.

Why is that? Think about it, via `myFruits` reference you will be able to store any kind of Fruit in set, so would it be OK to let you pass `Apple` if reference holds set of `Banana`s?

That is why if you declare reference of type `Set<Map<whatever>` it can hold only instance which are meant to hold all kinds of `Map`s, not just `HashMaps`.

So

```
Set<Map<Character, Integer>> v3 = new HashSet<Map<Character, Integer>>();
//  ^^^                                       ^^^
```

this generic types have to be te the seme